# Write file permissions for root user

Tags: linux, command-line, file-permissions

I have a file called `myfile` that I would like to move using:

```
sudo mv myfile deep-dark-directory/
```

I need to use `sudo` to move the file as `deep-dark-directory` needs root privileges to write and I can't change the permissions of the `deep-dark-directory`.

How can I change the permissions/ownership of `myfile` so that the root user can move it ?

Attempt 1:

```
$ chown root myfile 
chown: changing ownership of `myfile': Operation not permitted
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ sudo chown root myfile 
chown: changing ownership of `myfile': Operation not permitted
```

Attempt 3:

```
$ chmod a+x myfile
$ ls -l index.html.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hh360 hh360 10819 May 15 12:08 myfile
$ sudo mv myfile deep-dark-directory/
mv: cannot remove `myfile': Permission denied
```

Attempt 4 :

```
$ sudo chmod a+x myfile
chmod: changing permissions of `myfile': Operation not permitted
```

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: is the file currently in use?

Comment: nope. and its nothing special, just a simple text file

Comment: is deep-dark-directory/ on a network drive?  Root (uid 0) often has _less_ priveleges on network drives than does a normal user.  (This is particularly true of network drives using NFS protocol.)

Comment: Also: what are the perimissions on the directory _containing_ `myfile`?  It looks like that directory is not permitting you to modify the directory (remove files, change their permissions.)

Comment: deep-dark-directory is /usr/local/bin

Comment: all I can say is I've done what you are trying a thousand times, and I see no problems with your commands, other than they are somewhat implicit. try explicitly specifying the paths or at least using ./, and use the full form for chown, but it should work as written, assuming you are at the right path in the first place.

Comment: Try copying the file instead.  Attempt #3 shows that it's error'ing on removal of the file not placing the file in the dst directory.

Comment: myfile is in my home directory permissions are: drwxr-xr-x 56 hh360 hh360 8192 May 15 13:06 hh360

Comment: I've worked around by splitting `sudo mv myfile deep-dark-directory/` into `sudo cp myfile deep-dark-directory/' and 'rm myfile' but I still don't understand why this I couldn't do this

Comment: Fixed, turns out my home directory was on a networked drive as highlighted by @WanderingLogic

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to have write permission in your current working directory:

```
chmod u+w .
```

Comment: since it was root on nfs drive, what was needed was probably "chmod o+w ."